# ReactJS - open existing project in local server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**Update 30 May -
Thankyou everyone for your responses.
I didn't have any luck with this project (I think the folders were all over the place, and as I am a beginner I couldn't resolve it, so I chose to not use it). However I downloaded another free React template/project off the internet and all of the advice I received on this page helped me to open it. Big thanks to everyone on here

---

I am a ReactJS beginner.
I am trying to open an existing completed ReactJS project through VS Code and then preview the output in my web browser through local server. This was a project I downloaded off the internet. I am used to using ‘**npm start**’ in the terminal to preview the output with react projects I have built myself. However, this is not working when I try to access a project someone else created. When I open this project through VS Code and put ‘**npm start**’ in the terminal it doesn’t work for me : /

I have looked around stackoverflow but I have not found an answer to this question..

I tried this instruction [here](https://reactgo.com/npm-err-missing-script/) - but it still did not work

I get this error:

```
PS D:\Downloads\react-admin-master> npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-28T04_18_31_314Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated : )

**update - the package.json file contents

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "react-admin-lerna",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "lerna run build",
        "watch": "lerna run --parallel watch",
        "test-unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test cross-env BABEL_ENV=cjs NODE_ICU_DATA=./node_modules/full-icu jest",
        "test-unit-ci": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test cross-env BABEL_ENV=cjs NODE_ICU_DATA=./node_modules/full-icu jest --runInBand",
        "test-e2e": "yarn run -s build && cross-env NODE_ENV=test && cd cypress && yarn -s test",
        "test-e2e-local": "cd cypress && yarn -s start",
        "test": "yarn -s test-unit && yarn -s test-e2e",
        "doc": "cd docs && jekyll server . --watch",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx \"./packages/**/src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" \"./examples/**/src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" \"./cypress/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\"",
        "prettier": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc.js --write --list-different \"packages/*/src/**/*.{js,json,ts,tsx,css,md}\" \"examples/*/src/**/*.{js,ts,json,tsx,css,md}\" \"cypress/**/*.{js,ts,json,tsx,css,md}\"",
        "run-simple": "cd examples/simple && yarn -s start",
        "run-no-code": "cd examples/no-code && yarn dev",
        "run-tutorial": "cd examples/tutorial && yarn -s start",
        "run-demo": "cd examples/demo && cross-env REACT_APP_DATA_PROVIDER=rest yarn -s start",
        "build-demo": "cd examples/demo && cross-env REACT_APP_DATA_PROVIDER=rest yarn -s build",
        "run-graphql-demo": "cd examples/demo && cross-env REACT_APP_DATA_PROVIDER=graphql yarn -s start",
        "run-demo-watch": "concurrently \"yarn run watch\" \"yarn run run-demo\"",
        "run-graphql-demo-watch": "concurrently \"yarn run watch\" \"yarn run run-graphql-demo\"",
        "run-crm": "cd examples/crm && yarn -s start",
        "build-crm": "cd examples/crm && yarn -s build"
    },
    "jest": {
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "./test-setup.js"
        ],
        "preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/",
            "/lib/",
            "/esm/",
            "/examples/simple/"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$"
        ],
        "globals": {
            "ts-jest": {
                "isolatedModules": true
            }
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "cheerio": "~1.0.0-rc.2",
        "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "eslint": "^7.7.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.1",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
        "express": "~4.16.3",
        "full-icu": "~1.3.1",
        "husky": "^2.3.0",
        "jest": "26.6.0",
        "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
        "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
        "lerna": "~2.9.1",
        "lint-staged": "^8.1.7",
        "lolex": "~2.3.2",
        "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
        "prettier": "~2.1.1",
        "raf": "~3.4.1",
        "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
        "wait-on": "^3.2.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/*",
        "examples/*",
        "cypress"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "typescript": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: hello!, the npm tasks are defined in the `package.json` file, in the `script` property, paste the content of that file here so I can help you

Comment: Anything in `scripts` can be executed. You likely want to start with `npm run run-tutorial`. Replace `run-tutorial` with any other key if needed. I'm not sure how the rest of the project looks like, but since you stated you are beginner you might want to start with something much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2

your app should start by running `yarn run-tutorial` or `npm run run-tutorial` judging by the package.json file its using yarn as its package manager but should work with NPM just fine. If it doesnt, install yarn here https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

--

Edit 1

as a side note though, if you downloaded the app off the internet it may not run using `npm start` thats just a generic command to start apps. If you include the contents of the entire `package.json` file it will list out the different commands available to start the app or perform other tasks

--

Original answer

your `package.json` file will need to be opened and add the following code:

```json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

if you have named your javascript file something different than `app.js` it will be whatever you have named your root file

Comment: Hello alilland, thankyou for your reply. How do I know which is the root file for the ReactJS project? (Sorry I'm a reactjs beginner)

Comment: @PastaBolognaise753 usually its `index.js` or `./src/index.js`

Comment: i went ahead and updated my answer as well